# I am confused about Firebase Rules

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

If my Firebase rules are like this:

`{ "rules": { ".read": true, ".write": true } }`

then, anyone can read and write/modify the database.
How it can be possible even they don't know the link??
I have made an android app based on the `Firebase database` and users data will be stored in this database. If I publish this app in `google playstore` with this rules,
Is is problematic?

What does it mean by "anyone can read and write"??
can anyone please explain??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> anyone can read and write/modify the database. How it can be possible even they don't know the link??

> If I publish this app in google playstore with this rules, Is is problematic?

After you publish your app, the name of your project will become public information to the world simply by reverse engineering your APK.  Once they have that, they can use the public REST API to read and write the entire database.

You should use Firebase Authentication along with security rules to determine which authenticated users are actually allowed to read and write various locations in the database, as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security#section-authentication).

Comment: If my rules are "auth != null" for both reading and writing? 
Then will it be problem free??

Comment: Only you can determine what rules are appropriate for your app.  Since I don't know what your app does, the data it deals with, or how you expect that data to be protected, I can't give any advice.  You will need to implement rules according to your specific needs.